# I'm getting this error "unable to include header file windows.h"

Tags: c, header-files, turbo-c++

I'm writing my code in C, it's a code for a snake game.
when i run it i got this error **"ERROR: unable to open windows.h "**,
I'hv  downloaded windows.h from SourceForge but still the code didn't run,
I got another error **"ERROR : unable to open _mingw.h"**, I did the same thing with this file but still the code didn't work, then it shows **"ERROR: unable to open skddver.h "**, even after downloading this file (i.e skddver.h), it shows the same error **"ERROR: unable to open skddver.h "**. 
please help me I'm using turboC++ compiler(3.2).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <process.h>

#define UP 72
#define DOWN 80
#define LEFT 75
#define RIGHT 77

int length;
int bend_no;
int len;
char key;
void record();
void load();
int life;
void Delay(long double);
void Move();
void Food();
int Score();
void Print();
void gotoxy(int x, int y);
void GotoXY(int x,int y);
void Bend();
void Boarder();
void Down();
void Left();
void Up();
void Right();
void ExitGame();
int Scoreonly();

struct coordinate{
    int x;
    int y;
    int direction;
};

typedef struct coordinate coordinate;

coordinate head, bend[500],food,body[30];

int main()
{

    char key;

    Print();

    system("cls");

    load();

    length=5;

    head.x=25;

    head.y=20;

    head.direction=RIGHT;

    Boarder();

    Food(); //to generate food coordinates initially

    life=3; //number of extra lives

    bend[0]=head;

    Move();   //initialing initial bend coordinate

    return 0;

}

void Move()
{
    int a,i;

    do{

        Food();
        fflush(stdin);

        len=0;

        for(i=0;i<30;i++)

        {

            body[i].x=0;

            body[i].y=0;

            if(i==length)

            break;

        }

        Delay(length);

        Boarder();

        if(head.direction==RIGHT)

            Right();

        else if(head.direction==LEFT)

            Left();

        else if(head.direction==DOWN)

            Down();

        else if(head.direction==UP)

            Up();

        ExitGame();

    }while(!kbhit());

    a=getch();

    if(a==27)

    {

        system("cls");

        exit(0);

    }
    key=getch();

    if((key==RIGHT&&head.direction!=LEFT&&head.direction!=RIGHT)||(key==LEFT&&head.direction!=RIGHT&&head.direction!=LEFT)||(key==UP&&head.direction!=DOWN&&head.direction!=UP)||(key==DOWN&&head.direction!=UP&&head.direction!=DOWN))

    {

        bend_no++;

        bend[bend_no]=head;

        head.direction=key;

        if(key==UP)

            head.y--;

        if(key==DOWN)

            head.y++;

        if(key==RIGHT)

            head.x++;

        if(key==LEFT)

            head.x--;

        Move();

    }

    else if(key==27)

    {

        system("cls");

        exit(0);

    }

    else

    {

        printf("\a");

        Move();

    }
}

void gotoxy(int x, int y)
{

 COORD coord;

 coord.X = x;

 coord.Y = y;

 SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), coord);

}
void GotoXY(int x, int y)
{
    HANDLE a;
    COORD b;
    fflush(stdout);
    b.X = x;
    b.Y = y;
    a = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(a,b);
 }
void load(){
    int row,col,r,c,q;
    gotoxy(36,14);
    printf("loading...");
    gotoxy(30,15);
    for(r=1;r<=20;r++){
    for(q=0;q<=100000000;q++);//to display the character slowly
    printf("%c",177);}
    getch();
}
void Down()
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<=(head.y-bend[bend_no].y)&&len<length;i++)
    {
        GotoXY(head.x,head.y-i);
        {
            if(len==0)
                printf("v");
            else
                printf("*");
        }
        body[len].x=head.x;
        body[len].y=head.y-i;
        len++;
    }
    Bend();
    if(!kbhit())
        head.y++;
}
void Delay(long double k)
{
    Score();
    long double i;
    for(i=0;i<=(10000000);i++);
}
void ExitGame()
{
    int i,check=0;
    for(i=4;i<length;i++)   //starts with 4 because it needs minimum 4 element to touch its own body
    {
        if(body[0].x==body[i].x&&body[0].y==body[i].y)
        {
            check++;    //check's value increases as the coordinates of head is equal to any other body coordinate
        }
        if(i==length||check!=0)
            break;
    }
    if(head.x<=10||head.x>=70||head.y<=10||head.y>=30||check!=0)
    {
        life--;
        if(life>=0)
        {
            head.x=25;
            head.y=20;
            bend_no=0;
            head.direction=RIGHT;
            Move();
        }
        else
        {
            system("cls");
            printf("All lives completed\nBetter Luck Next Time!!!\nPress any key to quit the game\n");
            record();
            exit(0);
        }
    }
}
void Food()
{
    if(head.x==food.x&&head.y==food.y)
    {
        length++;
        time_t a;
        a=time(0);
        srand(a);
        food.x=rand()%70;
        if(food.x<=10)
            food.x+=11;
        food.y=rand()%30;
        if(food.y<=10)

            food.y+=11;
    }
    else if(food.x==0)/*to create food for the first time coz global variable are initialized with 0*/
    {
        food.x=rand()%70;
        if(food.x<=10)
            food.x+=11;
        food.y=rand()%30;
        if(food.y<=10)
            food.y+=11;
    }
}
void Left()
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<=(bend[bend_no].x-head.x)&&len<length;i++)
    {
        GotoXY((head.x+i),head.y);
       {
                if(len==0)
                    printf("<");
                else
                    printf("*");
        }
        body[len].x=head.x+i;
        body[len].y=head.y;
        len++;
    }
    Bend();
    if(!kbhit())
        head.x--;

}
void Right()
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<=(head.x-bend[bend_no].x)&&len<length;i++)
    {
        //GotoXY((head.x-i),head.y);
        body[len].x=head.x-i;
        body[len].y=head.y;
        GotoXY(body[len].x,body[len].y);
        {
            if(len==0)
                printf(">");
            else
                printf("*");
        }
        /*body[len].x=head.x-i;
        body[len].y=head.y;*/
        len++;
    }
    Bend();
    if(!kbhit())
        head.x++;
}
void Bend()
{
    int i,j,diff;
    for(i=bend_no;i>=0&&len<length;i--)
    {
            if(bend[i].x==bend[i-1].x)
            {
                diff=bend[i].y-bend[i-1].y;
                if(diff<0)
                    for(j=1;j<=(-diff);j++)
                    {
                        body[len].x=bend[i].x;
                        body[len].y=bend[i].y+j;
                        GotoXY(body[len].x,body[len].y);
                        printf("*");
                        len++;
                        if(len==length)
                            break;
                    }
                else if(diff>0)
                    for(j=1;j<=diff;j++)
                    {
                        /*GotoXY(bend[i].x,(bend[i].y-j));
                        printf("*");*/
                        body[len].x=bend[i].x;
                        body[len].y=bend[i].y-j;
                        GotoXY(body[len].x,body[len].y);
                        printf("*");
                        len++;
                        if(len==length)
                            break;
                    }
            }
        else if(bend[i].y==bend[i-1].y)
        {
            diff=bend[i].x-bend[i-1].x;
            if(diff<0)
                for(j=1;j<=(-diff)&&len<length;j++)
                {
                    /*GotoXY((bend[i].x+j),bend[i].y);
                    printf("*");*/
                    body[len].x=bend[i].x+j;
                    body[len].y=bend[i].y;
                    GotoXY(body[len].x,body[len].y);
                        printf("*");
                   len++;
                   if(len==length)
                           break;
               }
           else if(diff>0)
               for(j=1;j<=diff&&len<length;j++)
               {
                   /*GotoXY((bend[i].x-j),bend[i].y);
                   printf("*");*/
                   body[len].x=bend[i].x-j;
                   body[len].y=bend[i].y;
                   GotoXY(body[len].x,body[len].y);
                       printf("*");
                   len++;
                   if(len==length)
                       break;
               }
       }
   }
}
void Boarder()
{
   system("cls");
   int i;
   GotoXY(food.x,food.y);   /*displaying food*/
       printf("F");
   for(i=10;i<71;i++)
   {
       GotoXY(i,10);
           printf("!");
       GotoXY(i,30);
           printf("!");
   }
   for(i=10;i<31;i++)
   {
       GotoXY(10,i);
           printf("!");
       GotoXY(70,i);
       printf("!");
   }
}
void Print()
{
   //GotoXY(10,12);
   printf("\tWelcome to the mini Snake game.(press any key to continue)\n");
  getch();
   system("cls");
   printf("\tGame instructions:\n");
   printf("\n-> Use arrow keys to move the snake.\n\n-> You will be provided foods at the several coordinates of the screen which you have to eat. Everytime you eat a food the length of the snake will be increased by 1 element and thus the score.\n\n-> Here you are provided with three lives. Your life will decrease as you hit the wall or snake's body.\n\n-> YOu can pause the game in its middle by pressing any key. To continue the paused game press any other key once again\n\n-> If you want to exit press esc. \n");
   printf("\n\nPress any key to play game...");
   if(getch()==27)
   exit(0);
}
void record(){
   char plname[20],nplname[20],cha,c;
   int i,j,px;
   FILE *info;
   info=fopen("record.txt","a+");
   getch();
   system("cls");
   printf("Enter your name\n");
   scanf("%[^\n]",plname);
   //************************
   for(j=0;plname[j]!='\0';j++){ //to convert the first letter after space to capital
   nplname[0]=toupper(plname[0]);
   if(plname[j-1]==' '){
   nplname[j]=toupper(plname[j]);
   nplname[j-1]=plname[j-1];}
   else nplname[j]=plname[j];
   }
   nplname[j]='\0';
   //*****************************
   //sdfprintf(info,"\t\t\tPlayers List\n");
   fprintf(info,"Player Name :%s\n",nplname);
    //for date and time

   time_t mytime;
  mytime = time(NULL);
  fprintf(info,"Played Date:%s",ctime(&mytime));
     //**************************
     fprintf(info,"Score:%d\n",px=Scoreonly());//call score to display score
     //fprintf(info,"\nLevel:%d\n",10);//call level to display level
   for(i=0;i<=50;i++)
   fprintf(info,"%c",'_');
   fprintf(info,"\n");
   fclose(info);
   printf("wanna see past records press 'y'\n");
   cha=getch();
   system("cls");
   if(cha=='y'){
   info=fopen("record.txt","r");
   do{
       putchar(c=getc(info));
       }while(c!=EOF);}
     fclose(info);
}
int Score()
{
   int score;
   GotoXY(20,8);
   score=length-5;
   printf("SCORE : %d",(length-5));
   score=length-5;
   GotoXY(50,8);
   printf("Life : %d",life);
   return score;
}
int Scoreonly()
{
int score=Score();
system("cls");
return score;
}
void Up()
{
   int i;
   for(i=0;i<=(bend[bend_no].y-head.y)&&len<length;i++)
   {
       GotoXY(head.x,head.y+i);
       {
           if(len==0)
               printf("^");
           else
               printf("*");
       }
       body[len].x=head.x;
       body[len].y=head.y+i;
       len++;
   }
   Bend();
   if(!kbhit())
       head.y--;
}
```

Comment: `please help me I'm using turboC++ compiler(3.2).` Ditch that and then ask for help.

Comment: There is absolutely no chance you can include `windows.h` and `process.h` using TurboC++. This compiler is most likely older than you. Dont use TurboC. It's a dead product. It's totally obsolete. Its has expired. It is no more. It has ceased to live. Don't use it, ever. Forget about its existence. Really.

Comment: This is definitely not a **MINIMAL**, Complete, and Verifiable example. You could easily reduce by 90%.

Comment: the header file: `time.h`  only needs to be included once.

Comment: the posted code contains several 'magic' numbers.  'magic' numbers are numbers with no basis.  'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  Suggest using a `enum` statement or `#define` statements to give those 'magic' numbers meaningful names, then use those meaningful names throughout the code.

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding" 1) avoid useless blank lines. However, do separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a single blank line.  2) insert appropriate horizontal space inside parens, around C operators, after commas, after semicolons, etc.  3) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: when writing prototypes for functions that do not take any parameters, the prototype must have `void` between the parens.  Note: the actual function does not (and should not) have the `void` between the parens

Comment: this statement: `fflush(stdin);`, while Visual Studio does not flag it, the C standard specifically states that calling `fflush()` on an input stream is undefined behavior.  Suggest: `int ch;  for( (ch = getchar() ) != EOF && '\n' != ch );`

Comment: there are some calls to `getch()`  (which is non portable) without first prompting the user as to what to enter next

Comment: it is a very poor programming practice to have variable names and/or function names those only difference is the capitalization.  so `gotoxy()` and `Gotoxy()`  needs to be corrected such that they are very unique names

Comment: in general, it is best to keep data instances as local as possible to where they are used.  So this: `int i; for(i=0;i<=(head.y-bend[bend_no].y)&&len<length;i++)` should be written as: `for( int i=0;i<=(head.y-bend[bend_no].y) && len<length; i++ )

Comment: regarding: `        GotoXY(head.x,head.y-i);
        {
            if(len==0)
                printf("v");
            else
                printf("*");
        }`   what are the braces '{' and '}' expected to provide?

Comment: the data type: `COORD` is not defined anywhere in the posted code.

Comment: regarding this statement in `food()`,  `srand(a);`  the function `srand()` should only be called once during the whole program execution.  preferably in the first part of the `main()` function

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding, please indent the code consistently.  Random indented blocks make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, etc

Comment: when calling `fopen()`, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful,

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, 1) always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.  2) when using the '%s' or the '[,,,]' input conversion specifiers, always include a MAX CHARACTERS modifier that is 1 less than the length of the input buffer, to avoid any buffer overflow (which would be undefined behavior and can lead to a seg fault event.

Comment: the posted code never tells the user that entering a '27' (escape key) can be used to exit the game, so why would you expect the user to be using the key to exit the game?

Comment: regarding: `for(j=0;plname[j]!='\0';j++)
   { //to convert the first letter after space to capital
        nplname[0]=toupper(plname[0]);`  the call to `toupper()` will be executed for every letter in the char string 'plname' and always for the first char in the name

Comment: regarding my prior comment:  this statement: `if(plname[j-1]==' ')` will be trying to access a -1 offset into the array 'plname[]'  This is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

TurcoC++ is an ancient, a discontinued C++ compiler, and thus you should abandond it.

You cannot include `windows.h` and `process.h`, by using TurboC++.

Please use another, modern, compiler, like GCC for example.